# Ransack sorting deep associations is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, associations, ransack

I have many to many relations between models:

```
model1 has many model2
model2 has many model3
model3 has one model4
```

sorting on attributes that come from `model1` is working, but it didn't work neither for :

```
 `model2_attr` or `model2_first_model3_first_attr` or `model2_first_model3_first_model4_attr`
```

Update: I have a grid and I want the sort to be based on string field inside the `model3`, and it comes from the decorator not from the model.